# DRAW (print - not the graph) an equation in Quartz (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, cocoa, drawing, quartz-graphics, equations

I'm trying to draw equations to the screen. Not the graphs or sth just the equation, but in a "pretty" way (f.e. like they look on wikipedia ).
I've done some research but could find a "build-in-way", but maybe i overlooked something?!?

So i've decided to draw them by myself. I'm not very experienced, so don't blaim me if my idea is completely idiotic...

I thought of two ways. Either i create one UIView subclass hand in the formula as string, parse it and handle all the drawing in that view. Or i create individual subclasses for each type of mathematical expression  and hand in the apropriate parts (f.e numerator and denominator for a fraction). and those parts can be either of those subclasses... f.e. a (square)-root-subclass would get the part under the root and draws the root-sign at the appropriate place in the appropriate size...

is one of this ways any good? or if some knows an better/easier way to solve this, pls let me know.

would help me alot,
thanks

Comment: Similar question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907045/drawing-formulas-with-quartz-2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pour a [MathML expression](http://www.flickr.com/photos/__olga__/2968076110/) into a `UIWebView`.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, that would be my backup-plan. but i'd like to have more flexibility, to manipulate them onscreen.

Comment: You're looking at managing a fairly complex object graph, comprised of layers of graphical elements. Not impossible, but it would be a fair amount of work.

Comment: As can be seen on the linked photo, the rendering of MathML expressions in the current Webkit is not exactly adequate. Just look at the second expression (y_i = ...): the fraction is displaced quite a bit from the correct position.