# Math rendering library for iPhone OS

Tags: iphone, math, latex, rendering, mathml

Is there a library to render mathematical equations that can be used in iPhone OS?

I would be very happy with a library that renders MathML or LaTeX to a format that iPhone OS can display. 
If the lib were licensed under BSD (or similar), that would be perfect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing formulas with Quartz 2d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907045/drawing-formulas-with-quartz-2d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer myself: there is currently (June 2011) no such library. (I ended up hacking something myself.)

If you're ready to use WebKit, you can hope for proper MathML support which you can then use with a `UIWebView`.

MathML is apparently included in desktop Safari 5.1, which hopefully means that it will also be in iOS 5's Mobile Safari.