# Display Math Notation and Math Questions on View?

Tags: ios, ios4

Anyone know how to display math question include math notation in view? For example: 8 to the power of 2 ; square root of 16.

Any suggestions, methods and comments are appreciated. Thanks :-)

Comment: What is the question here? Are you asking for mathematical notation on calculators? A common inline symbol for "power" is `^`.

Comment: My question is I need to display a view that consists of mathematic question. But I don't know how to display some of the question, for example 3 to the power of 5. Yes, I know the inline symbol is ^. But I wish to display it as 3 with a superscript 5 beside 3. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: How about CSS? That has dedicated [sub/superscript](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) support.

Comment: Does IOS support and able work with CSS?

Comment: I appreciate that it could be formulated better, but I see this as a valid question. Voted for reopen.

Comment: @Kate: I don't know iOS, but if you're using some sort of webkitty presentation technology, you can render HTML and use CSS. And even the standard widgets might accept a "rich" presentation style that's essentially expressed in HTML+CSS. But I'm not sure on that one, best to consult your favourite iOS programming guide.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like [MathML](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML/) used in web frameworks like [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/)?

I don't believe there is any in-built support for anything like this in IOS.

You could try to 'hack' something together with a IOS UIWebView like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3491971/23235) question states.

Comment: Yes, is something like MathML and MathJax. I wish to display mathematics question include those mathematics notation in view. Yes, IOS seems not have any in-built support. Ok, I will try to "hack" something together with UIWebView. Really thanks for your help. :-) And I have a question is how about if I save those Mathematics Question as image files and then display them on view? Is it a proper way?