# Parse image to SESHAT tool?

Tags: ios, parsing, web, mathml, inkml

I am trying to create a simple tool that uses this website's functionality http://cat.prhlt.upv.es/mer/ which parses some strokes of text to a math formula. I noticed that they mention that it converts the input to InkML or MathML.

Now I noticed that according to this link: [Tradeoff between LaTex, MathML, and XHTMLMathML in an iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243539/tradeoff-between-latex-mathml-and-xhtmlmathml-in-an-ios-app) you can use MathJax to convert certain input to MathML.

What I need clarification/assistance with is how can I take input (say from finger strokes) or a picture and then convert it to a format in which I can provide this website from an iOS device and read the result at the top of the page. I have done everything regarding taking a picture or drawing an equation on an iPhone but I am just confused how I can take that and feed it to this site in order to get a result.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a misunderstanding here. http://cat.prhlt.upv.es/mer/ isn't an API for converting images into formulae—it's just an example demonstration of the [Seshat software tool](https://github.com/falvaro/seshat).

If you're looking to convert hand-drawn math expressions into LaTeX or MathML (which can then be pretty printed on your device), you want to compile Seshat and then feed *it*, not the website, your input. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574812/convert-stroke-data-to-scg-ink-format/34076013#34076013) explains how to format input for Seshat.